# How to configure Eclipse CDT to use WAF for ns3 build?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, waf, ns-3

I'm trying to build ns3 on windows, and I'm using eclipse.
I have a problem to configure Eclipse to trigger the external builder tool "waf"
Each time I adjust the build command I get an error, as eclipse seems not to be able to trigger the waf script

Any help with that, I have tried the HOWto Page on ns3 WiKi but it doesn't seem to be working with me

[image: Eclipse configuration]
[image: Building Error for WAF]

Comment: Screenshots, what error?

Comment: I have just added screen shots

Comment: Can you show the errors as text scrennshots ar not easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Default NS-3 does not run with native Windows compiler. There is an 'experimental' version of NS-3 that can run on Visual Studio. For more information read this: http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Ns-3_on_Visual_Studio_2012